# Can Element.ClassList.add() function be asynchronous?

Tags: javascript

I know that classList.add() function is synchronous but if i wrap classList.add() into async function and run it like this:

```
const ca = async function(elem,clss){
    elem.classList.add(clss);
}
for(let i = 0; i < number; ++i){
    await ca(somediv[i],"classname");
}
```

Then it will be asynchronous or not?

If not then is there any way to add classes to elements asynchronously?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252737/discussion-on-question-by-gurami-nikolaishvili-can-element-classlist-add-funct); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `async`. Just run them whenever the main thread is idle using `setTimeout()`.

```
elems.forEach(elem => setTimeout(() => elem.classList.add("someclass"), 0));
```

If this is too slow because of the number of timeouts, you could batch them.

```
const chunkSize = 50;
for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const chunk = elems.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
    setTimeout(() => chunk.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("someclass")), 0);
}
```

Comment: adding setTimeout increased loop executing from 800ms to 1300ms

Comment: Then I guess it's not worth it. Adding a class is a really cheap operation, faster than creating a timer.

Comment: It is not cheap when you have 370+ elements)

Comment: You could try batching them up instead of creating a separate timer for each element.

Comment: could you explain how?

Comment: Added that to the answer.

Comment: it tooks longer.

Comment: @GuramiNikolaishvili how are you measuring the performance?